# Iterator supposed to return HashSet but acts as Object

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

```
private ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> sets = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>();

            Iterator i = this.sets.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()){

                if(i.next().containsAll(union)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

I get the following exception as it asssumes .next() gets an object of type Object

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to HashSet<Integer>
    The method containsAll(HashSet<Integer>) is undefined for the type Object
```

While I get the object Hash set

```
        while (i.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(i.next().getClass().getName());
        }
```

prints

```
java.util.HashSet
java.util.HashSet
java.util.HashSet
```

What's going on ?

Comment: getName() method will return the name of the class. Here the class name is java.util.HashSet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Iterator also as type of `HashSet`

```
Iterator<HashSet<Integer>> i = this.sets.iterator();
```

Comment: Ok, you've been 5 sec faster, removed my answer.

Comment: @home: Yeah, still you can your answer. Don't need to delete.

Comment: Thank you all, it worked, I'm new to java and I really do not understand that weird nested type casting, can you recommend anything to read ?

Comment: You need to read about Generics.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Yea I'm trying but stacckoverflow does not take it, untill I wait for a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Fairly easy, replace

```
Iterator i = this.sets.iterator();
```

with

```
Iterator<HashSet<Integer>> i = this.sets.iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it explicitly or make it generic

```
private ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> sets = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>();

            Iterator<HashSet<Integer>> i = this.sets.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()){

                if(i.next().containsAll(union)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the Iterator also in a

```
 Iterator<HashSet<Integer>> i = sets.iterator();
```

It should then be able to cast it to HashSet automatically. Otherwise you will need to do explicit casting

```
if(((HashSet<Integer>)i.next()).containsAll(union)){
                //return true;
            }
```